# SQL Server throwing errors when trying to reference newly created column in already existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

When trying to reference/access newly added column to existing (or not?) table, I am always getting editor error and most of the time execution error (most != always, which is even weirder).

Consider the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Products 
ADD TotalSales INT NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT Def DEFAULT 0

UPDATE P
SET P.TotalSales = TEMP.TotalSalesComputed
FROM Products P 
JOIN
    (SELECT ProductID, SUM(OD.Quantity) TotalSalesComputed
     FROM [Order Details] OD
     GROUP BY ProductID) TEMP ON P.ProductID = TEMP.ProductID
```

Now, editor says:

> Invalid column name 'TotalSales'.

On execution:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 151
>   Invalid column name 'TotalSales'.

Which is same.

What's even worse is that even if I have the error in editor - SOMETIMES (as of now - random) query is successful (it does what it should).

I tried IntelliSense's cache-clearing, then some EXEC stuff, read something about similar problems - yet nothing.

People say stuff about SQL Server compiling script before running it and effectively detecting "Invalid column" error and not actually firing query.

Is there some command (like EXEC one) which would ensure that this query is fired? (I don't care about editor error).

Comment: Have you tried inserting a GO after the alter statement?

Comment: The batch is compiled against the existing table definition.  You'll get errors if you reference the new column in the same batch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Put

> GO

into the two Queries.

Go is Signals the end of a batch.

so your query will be as the following

```
 ALTER TABLE Products ADD TotalSales INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Def DEFAULT 0
 Go -- added
 UPDATE P
 SET P.TotalSales = TEMP.TotalSalesComputed
 FROM Products P
 JOIN
(
     SELECT ProductID, SUM(OD.Quantity) TotalSalesComputed
     FROM [Order Details] OD
     GROUP BY ProductID
 ) TEMP
ON P.ProductID = TEMP.ProductID
```

Referance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx